# Python, UnicodeDecodeError trying to print exception that contains non ascii chars

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

When I get an exception as `cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'ÿ'.` and I try to print it, it raises a unicode decode error when I try to insert it into my (unicode) error message:

```
try:
    settings = _load()
except cPickle.UnpicklingError, err:
    msg = _(u"Error reading ... (the error is: '%s')")
    cont = askYes(msg % err, _(u"Settings Load Error")) # raises
```

Tried workarounds as in  `msg % unicode(err.message, encoding='utf-8')` but apparently `err.message` is not valid unicode string ("UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 19: invalid start byte")

So what is the most pythonic way to handle this ? Should I pass 'ignore' or 'replace' to `unicode()` ?

Edit: `askYes(None, msg % repr(err), _(u"Settings Load Error"))` gives something like:

```
(the error is: 'UnpicklingError("invalid load key, '\xff'.",)'). # ff is ÿ
```

Does not blow but still...

Edit2: the errors I reported are a bit mixed up with artificial ones:

```
u'%s' % "cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'ÿ'."
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 44: ordinal \
    not in range(128)
```

That's from the interpreter inside pycharm - apparently `ÿ` is `'\xc3\xbf'` there (...)

Comment: Using `repr`, or more directly `%r` rather than `%s`, is the best way to display a string of dubious content -- it may or may not be intended to represent Unicode, but either the `\x0f` you show or the `0xff` you mention earlier make one ponder about the encoding.  If `err.message` is a random collection of bytes with no rhyme or reason, how could you possibly display it better than by `repr`?!  `ignore` or `replace` would hide potentially precious information for debugging purposes -- **never** do that in an error message!

Comment: @AlexMartelli: thanks - yes I would not use replace and co - I just wanted to fright people so they answer me :D. Could you elaborate on `repr` - would it be better to use repr(err.message)? I'd appreciate a full answer

Comment: @AlexMartelli: repr(err.message): `(the error is: '"invalid load key, '\x0f'."')` while repr(err): `(the error is: 'UnpicklingError("invalid load key, '\x0f'.",)')`. I'd rather have something in the lines of ` (the error is: UnpicklingError: "invalid load key, '\x0f'.")` - do I have to construct it manually ? Also I admit that _why `repr()` manages to decode the string escapes me_.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any Unicode problem in the string as shown: `'\x0f'` gives no such problem -- while `'\xff'` would.  Try decoding err.message as 'iso-8859-1', which cannot fail (it decodes every byte, though perhaps to a nonsense glyph), and you may learn more.  BTW, no surprise that `repr` has no problem -- `repr` never fails -- it's the alchemic transmutation between `'\xff'` and `'\x0f'` that leaves me puzzled!

Comment: @AlexMartelli: oh sorry about that - I may have transmutated the error messages - apparently `err.message` was `invalid load key, ' + chr(0xff)` in the "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec...position 19". How come repr never fails ? Does it use iso-8859-1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to ensure you can see the result in the error message is to use `repr`, or more directly `%r` rather than `%s`: that never fails (because any object has a representation, and all representations are in ASCII including possibly escape sequences), and also shows (as escape sequences) characters that might otherwise be invisible.

`repr` (and `'%r'` in old-style format strings) delegates to an object type's `__repr__` special method; each object type is responsible for knowing how to best represent itself in an unambiguous (not necessarily super-readable) ASCII character string.  Strings and byte sequences are particularly good at that, so `repr` is super-suitable for them.

The OP has done that but does not like the aesthetics of the result (varying between `repr` of `err.message` vs `repr` of `err`).  Unfortunately, aesthetics is the very least of priorities for `repr`: rather, it's all about complete, unambiguous information.

Another idea is to decode with a never-fail encoding (one which decodes every byte, though perhaps into a meaningless-in-context glyph), such as 'iso-8859-1'.  But it's no real improvement over `repr`, I believe; the improvement in aesthetics is quite debatable, and there is a possibility of loss in terms of "complete, unambiguous information".

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify some points:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> u'%s' % "cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'ÿ'."
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 44: ordinal not in range(128)
```

That is because python 2 helpfully tries to decode the string to insert it to the unicode string - the default encoding being ASCII - of course ascii can't decode  `'ÿ'` (decode means transform bytes to code points) - hence the exception. Below works as it does not try to decode anything - just displays the bytes - in ascii:

```
>>> '%s' % "cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'ÿ'."
"cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xc3\xbf'."
```

Below also works and (as console displays in ascii) displays the unicode byte value (that is *encodes* the unicode string - the bytes in there - to ascii chars):

```
>>> u'%s' % u"cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'ÿ'."
u"cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xff'."
```

Same logic as in:

```
>>> u'á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ'
u'\xe1, \xe9, \xed, \xf3, \xfa, \xfc, \xf1'
>>> 'á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ'
'\xc3\xa1, \xc3\xa9, \xc3\xad, \xc3\xb3, \xc3\xba, \xc3\xbc, \xc3\xb1'
```

It is this internal encoding/decoding that confused me - and still puzzles me a bit.